# Google Cloud Build failed, fork/exec ./gradlew: permission denied

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I was trying to deploy a test Spring Boot project to Google Cloud Run referring to this Quickstart guide by Google: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-java-service

I didn't follow the guide exactly, as I write the REST endpoints myself. The project can start up locally and I am able to access its endpoint though.

What I did follow is run `gcloud run deploy` at the root of the project, and follow the options in Quickstart.

The process failed at "Building Container" stage. Google Cloud Build log shows that it failed when it is executing something related to `fork/exec` and `./gradlew`. Below is a slice of the log.

```
Step #1: [builder] Warning: BOM table is deprecated in this buildpack api version, though it remains supported for backwards compatibility. Buildpack authors should write BOM information to <layer>.sbom.<ext>, launch.sbom.<ext>, or build.sbom.<ext>.
Step #1: [builder] === Java - Gradle (google.java.gradle@0.9.0) ===
Step #1: [builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #1: [builder] Running "./gradlew clean assemble -x test --build-cache --quiet"
Step #1: [builder] Done "./gradlew clean assemble -x test --build-cache --quiet" (396.638µs)
Step #1: [builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #1: [builder] failed to build: (error ID: 14f2a5b3):
Step #1: [builder] executing command "./gradlew clean assemble -x test --build-cache --quiet": fork/exec ./gradlew: permission denied
Step #1: [builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Step #1: [builder] Sorry your project couldn't be built.
Step #1: [builder] Our documentation explains ways to configure Buildpacks to better recognise your project:
Step #1: [builder]  -> https://cloud.google.com/docs/buildpacks/overview
```

I tried searching online for these keywords, but I can find none. The most prevalent result is to use `chmod +x ./gradlew`, but I don't think I am able to do that?

More information:

1. Below is the directory tree of my source code

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 1049-EA32
C:.
+---.gradle
¦   +---8.4
¦   ¦   +---checksums
¦   ¦   +---dependencies-accessors
¦   ¦   +---executionHistory
¦   ¦   +---fileChanges
¦   ¦   +---fileHashes
¦   ¦   +---vcsMetadata
¦   +---buildOutputCleanup
¦   +---vcs-1
+---.idea
+---build
¦   +---classes
¦   ¦   +---java
¦   ¦       +---main
¦   ¦       ¦   +---com
¦   ¦       ¦       +---jameshskoh
¦   ¦       ¦           +---cloudrundemo
¦   ¦       +---test
¦   ¦           +---com
¦   ¦               +---jameshskoh
¦   ¦                   +---cloudrundemo
¦   +---generated
¦   ¦   +---sources
¦   ¦       +---annotationProcessor
¦   ¦       ¦   +---java
¦   ¦       ¦       +---main
¦   ¦       ¦       +---test
¦   ¦       +---headers
¦   ¦           +---java
¦   ¦               +---main
¦   ¦               +---test
¦   +---libs
¦   +---reports
¦   ¦   +---tests
¦   ¦       +---test
¦   ¦           +---classes
¦   ¦           +---css
¦   ¦           +---js
¦   ¦           +---packages
¦   +---resources
¦   ¦   +---main
¦   ¦       +---static
¦   ¦       +---templates
¦   +---test-results
¦   ¦   +---test
¦   ¦       +---binary
¦   +---tmp
¦       +---bootJar
¦       +---compileJava
¦       +---compileTestJava
¦       +---jar
¦       +---test
+---gradle
¦   +---wrapper
+---src
    +---main
    ¦   +---java
    ¦   ¦   +---com
    ¦   ¦       +---jameshskoh
    ¦   ¦           +---cloudrundemo
    ¦   +---resources
    ¦       +---static
    ¦       +---templates
    +---test
        +---java
            +---com
                +---jameshskoh
                    +---cloudrundemo
```

Comment: My guess is that you have a file collision problem (files on the local system that should not be uploaded to Cloud Build). Do you have gradle installed in the same directory tree as the project you are deploying? If yes, ignore that subdirectory: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore

Comment: Thanks. I tried creating a `.gcloudignore` at the root and tried including `gradle`, `.gradle`, `gradle/`, `.gradle/`, and many of their combinations, and it still fails ...

Comment: Let me share my directory structure in the question

Comment: I recommend debugging this by creating a Docker image first. Create the `Dockerfile` configured for your application. Then test the container in Docker. Verify that the `.dockerignore` is correctly skipping directories that are not required for the container. Review this guide: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containerize-java#gradle

Comment: Note: I do not recommend using the guide in your post. When I build an app for Cloud Run I do many more things that the guide skips (Google is trying to simplify deploying but that sometimes breaks building apps). By creating the `Dockerfile` and `cloudbuild.yaml`, you can control each step.

Comment: I agree! I thought Cloud Run were a "plug-and-play" thing. I went down to working with Artifact Registry and Cloud Build and it works already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @John Hanley, **the short answer is not follow the tutorial**. Instead, you should do the following:

1. Build your own JAR file
2. Build your own Docker image
3. Submit the image to Artifact Registry
4. Use Cloud Run to start a Service using the image

1: use Maven or Gradle to build your JAR file.

2: create a Dockerfile at the root of the project. Below is a sample I used.

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./target/rest-demo-0.0.2-POC.jar /app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "rest-demo-0.0.2-POC.jar"]
```

3: Set up a repository in Artifact Registry, in a region of your choice, and then tag your image in the following format

```
<region-name>-docker.pkg.dev/<gcp-project-name>/<repository-name>/<short-image-name>
```

E.g.

```
asia-northeast2-docker.pkg.dev/playground-888888/rest-demo/rest-demo
```

4: should be straightforward

**Along the way you may discover that you do not have certain permissions. Grant yourself those permissions and try again.**

Also I didn't use this, but it may be helpful too: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containerize-java#gradle

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build from a Windows PC then this will fail using this method. This is because Windows filesystem has no concept of the executable flag like a Linux/UNIX filesystem.

To confirm this you can look at the source tar gzip'd file (tgz) in your Cloud Storage bucket. Download this tgz file from there, and open view it in 7zip for example, you'll see the permissions on gradlew script are rw-r-r

[gradlew shown as read-write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WpLZ.png)

You have a couple of options:

1. Switch to using a genuine Linux/UNIX environment to build your code from, where you'll need the gcloud tools installed etc.

or

2. Use your Google Cloud Console "Cloud Shell". You can upload your files and work from there.

In both above options, you'll still need to check that the gradlew script is executable before doing your first deploy:
chmod +x gradlew